# Sed to replace a script variable by certificate

Tags: bash, sed

I'd like to replace a variable in a script template by a public and private certificate.

For example, I've generated a `harbor.crt` public certificate and a `harbor.key` private key with the following command:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout /data/harbor.key -out /data/harbor.crt -subj "/CN=$LOCAL_IP" -addext "subjectAltName=IP:127.0.0.1,IP:$LOCAL_IP"
```

In a template script, I've the following variables I'd like to replace with the above files:

```
CFG_HARBOR_CRT="CRT"                    # Harbor registry certificate
CFG_HARBOR_KEY="KEY"                    # Harbor registry key
```

To replace those values, I've tried to do something like that:

```
HARBOR_CRT=`sudo cat /data/harbor.crt`
HARBOR_KEY=`sudo cat /data/harbor.key`
sudo sed -i "s/CFG_HARBOR_CRT\=\"[^\"]*\"/CFG_HARBOR_CRT\=\"$HARBOR_CRT\"/g" ./template-script.sh
sudo sed -i "s/CFG_HARBOR_KEY\=\"[^\"]*\"/CFG_HARBOR_KEY\=\"$HARBOR_KEY\"/g" ./template-script.sh
```

But both commands failed on: `sed: -e expression #1, char 70: unterminated` s' command`

Is there a way to use `sed` command with unescaped variables ?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and describe *what* you want to achieve, not *how*. First and foremost, it makes no sense to paste some base64 data from a PEM encoded certificate into shell script; the data is not a valid script. If you want to read an entire file into a shell variable, just quote it properly, e.g. `MY_CERT_DATA="$(< /file/with/pem_cert.crt)"`. If you want to *inline* the certificate data into a script, maybe use `awk`, print irrelevant script lines normally and paste in a multi-line variable value: `MY_CERT_DATA='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... <lines with base64> ...'`.

Comment: Your public certificate and private key are multi-lines strings. How do yo want them to be inserted in your template? A new line after the opening double-quote and before the closing one? Other?

Comment: I need to write the certificate into the shell script as it will be shared to another server. Server #1 generates various token and certificates that I need on server #2 to connect to #1.

Comment: if the objective is to push these files to another host ... why not look at a `sftp/scp` solution? altenratively, if you want to 'embed' these files into a script, with said script being copied (`sftp/scp`?) to another host, consider running the files through `base64` and embedding the `base64` data into the script, then on the other end run `base64 -d` to decrypt the data and store in the target files; using `base64` data should eliminate most (all?) of the `sed` headaches of dealing with special characters and/or trying to find a `sed` script delimiter that's not in the data

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso. That did the trick. I used `HARBOR_CRT=$(sudo cat /data/harbor.crt | base64 -w 0)` to convert certificate to B64 and `echo $CFG_HARBOR_CRT | base64 --decode` to decode. You can post an answer that I will accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling out of comments to get better visibility ...

Consider running the files through `base64` and embedding the result into the script, then on the other end run `base64 -d` to decrypt the data and store in the target files.

Using `base64` encoded data should eliminate most (all?) of the `sed` headaches of dealing with special characters and/or trying to find a `sed` script delimiter that's not in the data.

---

OP/Manitoba's reply comment:

That did the trick. I used `HARBOR_CRT=$(sudo cat /data/harbor.crt | base64 -w 0)` to convert certificate to B64 and `echo $CFG_HARBOR_CRT | base64 --decode` to decode.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's info missing here. Why use `sed` at all?

For the *simple* case, just replace the markers with file reads.

```
CFG_HARBOR_CRT="$(</data/harbor.crt)"
CFG_HARBOR_KEY="$(</data/harbor.key)"
```

That might mean you need to run the whole script with elevated priv's though, so I understand why you might not want to do that.

...*do* you need root to read those files?

If so, and if you don't want the whole script run as root, maybe this:

```
$: sed 's,^CFG_HARBOR_CRT="CRT",CFG_HARBOR_CRT="$(sudo cat /data/harbor.crt)",
        s,^CFG_HARBOR_KEY="KEY",CFG_HARBOR_KEY="$(sudo cat /data/harbor.key)",' tmpf
CFG_HARBOR_CRT="$(sudo cat /data/harbor.crt)"                    # Harbor registry certificate
CFG_HARBOR_KEY="$(sudo cat /data/harbor.key)"                    # Harbor registry key
```

Switching `/` to `,` as the demarcation reduces leaning toothpick syndrome.

Switching `...` to `$(...)` improves flexibility, stability, readability, etc.